# Change SQL Server service account

Tags: sql-server, service-account

I need to change the Service Account for Sql Server (i.e. I need SQL Server to run under a different account). Can I just change the account or do I need to perform some Sharepoint configuration as well please?

Thanks and Regards,

Joseph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the SQL Service Account without any additional changes to SharePoint. Make the changes and Restart the SQL Service. Ensure that the service account of SQL has the necessary rights in the operating system where the SQL Server is running.

The rights you need to configure for SharePoint service account on SQL Server is of **db_creator** and **securityadmin** security  roles. As long as these roles are in place , you are safe from access troubles.